# PL/JSON get both the value and the parameter in json list

Tags: json, plsql, plsqldeveloper, pljson

I need to get both the value and the parameter in a json list using pl/json library. For an example,

```
{TABLE:"TEST",Parameters:[{"PID":"bar"},{"PFOJ":"baz"},{"PCLI":"bar"}]}
```

I need to get the parameter and the corresponding value in the 'Prameters' list in this json object like,

```
param varchar2(20);
value varchar2(20);

param := get_param(1); //from Parameters list
value := get_value(1); //from Parameters list
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you attempted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the key name:

```
varchar2 key := parameter_obj.get_keys.get(1).get_string();
```